# Remove spaces in file through shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

I have a psv file having records something like this:

```
  Apple    | Banana     | I want to eat banana        | Carrot
```

As you can see the all the columns contain leading and trailing spaces
I used this command:

```
sed -i -r 's/\s+//g;/^$/d' fileName
```

to remove the blank spaces as well as blank lines. After which i got the result as:

```
Apple|Banana|Iwanttoeatbanana|Carrot
```

What my **expected Result** is somewhat like this:

```
Apple|Banana|I want to eat banana|Carrot
```

Please help me getting this desired result using shell script.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What, a Javascript dupe for a sed question? Hope you guys start reading question a bit more before closing.

Comment: @anubhava thanks for the feedback (though without the ping, I nearly missed it); updated now with a better dupe.

Comment: Thanks but as you can see that problem is bit different. 1. It is changing one delimiter to other. 2. It doesn't ask and doesn't address leading/trailing whitespaces in each line.

Comment: What do you want to do with a field with large internal spacing?  eg  `apple|I      want              to       eat       a banana   |`. Should the internal spaces be squeezed down to one space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `sed`:

```sh
sed -E 's/^[[:blank:]]+|[[:blank:]]*(\|)[[:blank:]]*|[[:blank:]]+$/\1/g' file

Apple|Banana|I want to eat banana|Carrot
```

**Explanation:**

- `^[[:blank:]]+`: Match 1 or more whitespaces after start
- `|`: OR
- `[[:blank:]]*(\|)[[:blank:]]*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces before and after a `|` and capture `|` in group #1
- `|`: OR
- `[[:blank:]]+$`: Match 1 or more whitespaces before end
- `Replacement is a` \1` that puts captured value of group #1 in replacement

---

An `awk` solution:

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]]*\\|[[:blank:]]*' -v OFS='|' '{
   gsub(/^[[:blank:]]+|[[:blank:]]+$/, ""); $1=$1} 1' file

Apple|Banana|I want to eat banana|Carrot
```

Comment: HI thank you for your answer, will it work for 'n' number of records in a file or just for 1 record?

Comment: @Sifu: It will work for all the lines of the input file. Please test and see.